# zabbix agent install not working on open SUSE 42.3

Tags: linux, zabbix, opensuse

I am trying to install zabbix-agent on openSUSE 42.3 but it gives me the following error (view attached image):

> Repository 'openSUSE-Leap-42.3-Apache' is invalid.
> [openSUSE-Leap-42.3-Apache|http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Apache/openSUSE_Leap_42.3/]
> Valid metadata not found at specified URL Please check if the URIs
> defined for this repository are pointing to a valid repository.
> Warning: Skipping repository 'openSUSE-Leap-42.3-Apache' because of
> the above error. File '/repodata/repomd.xml' not found on medium
> 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/perl/openSUSE_Leap_42.3/'[enter
> image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeayW.png)

Anyone has an idea how to solve this error?

Comment: you are missing the `repo.zabbix.com/zabbix` repository, so you can't install zabbix-agent.

Comment: I have already added the repo

Comment: it is not in the screenshot